# how to write a sentence politely asking to be in touch?

Tags: sentence-construction

Which of these sentences is the correct one? Or are both correct or incorrect?

> 1. If you have any further questions please do not hesitate **in contacting** me.
> 2. If you have any further questions please do not hesitate **to contact** me.

Comment: Sentence 2 looks better.

Answer (score 1):

> If you have any further questions**,** please do not hesitate *to contact* me. ✓

> **hesitate to do something**: to be worried about doing something, especially because you are not sure that it is right or appropriate
>   e.g. *If you'd like me to send you the book, then please don't hesitate to ask.*

Source: [Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/hesitate)

P.S. Don't forget to add a comma after the *if*-clause.